# Invariant relation in ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

It is well known that if function $g(x)$ is an invariant relation under ODE $\dot x = f(x)$ then $\frac{\displaystyle d}{\displaystyle dt}g = \lambda g$.

More precisely. Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$ and $g:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^k$ be smooth maps. Suppose that $g(x_0)=0$ implies $g\bigl(x(t,x_0)\bigr)=0$ for all $t$ where $x(t,x_0)$ denotes the solution  of the system $\dot x=f(x)$ starting at $x_0$.

**Prop.** If the Jacobian of $g$ is of full rank then there exists a smooth map $\lambda:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathrm{Mat}_{k\times k}(\mathbb{R})$ such that

$$
  \frac{d}{dt} g(x) = \lambda(x) g(x)\quad\mbox{ for all }\quad x\in\mathbb{R}^n
$$

The ideas belong to Levi-Civita.

I am interested in the situation when the Jacobian of $g$ is not of full rank. I can easely prove this result if the rank of the Jacobian is constant. Does the same result hold in general situation when the rank of the Jacobian varies from point to point ($\mathrm{rk}(dg(x))\ne\mathrm{rk}(dg(y))$ for some x,y)?